# Copy file to Drive C in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to copy a file to Drive C but it ended up copy to my USB drive where the powershell file located.
Please advise what should be the destination to refer to Drive C in powershell ? Thanks.

```
Copy-Item -Path "${PSScriptRoot}\Software\Browsers\Firefox Setup 103.0.2.exe" -Destination "$env:systemdrive"
```

Comment: `Copy-Item -Path  "C:\Path\copied_file" -Destination "C:\"`

Comment: Why are you using env:systemdrive instead of the actual drive path? Copy source c:\targetfolder will work just fine in PowerShell.

Comment: Becuz some PCs are not having WINDOWS in Drive C so I want to apply systemdrive like in CMD instead.